# Duplicate jquery ui problem

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, django-forms

I'm working on a Django project. But my problem is on JQuery.
I used [jquery.formset.js](http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/) JQuery plugin to add form dynamically in inline_formsets, formset_factories. And this works pretty nice. It duplicates the first row elements with its other decoration tags (like div, span, img..) and adds the new row in the bottom of the table. So the duplicated row can be appeared just like the origin.

I also uses [jquery ui (datepicker, autocomplete..etc)](http://jqueryui.com/demos/) in my forms.

The duplication copies everything, even the appended htmls by the datepickers and autocompletes, because the plugin tries not to leave any interface pieces. When it clones the first row, everything is cloned, even the events are cloned. So when i click on the newly appeared datepicker input the calendar event works on the first row's element.

I'm trying to find the decision. Here are what in my mind so far..

1. Declare the jquery ui (datepicker and autocomplete) as **live**? like

   $(".dates").live('...', function() { $(this).datepicker(); } )

   But I'm not sure which event should be handled for this. I guess it's impossible to handle the new created or appended elements.
2. Putting the script inside the row? right after the element

   $("#id_birthday_1").datepicker();

   It seems the best idea, but the duplication has already duplicated the extra elements/htmls. So it will re-render the element.
3. Should I edit the js plugin? like binding all the jquery ui's events' declarations, excepting the renders and appending and styling. That would be a huge mess. I don't want to mess up like this.. And every time if i need to add a new ui, i should edit that js constantly

[image]

Every ideas would be appreciated :)

Comment: I bet both boxes had the same ID

Comment: Actually no.. the js plugin creates new id using the form prefix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formset plugin can call a function when a new form is added, you could initialize the newly added fields there. The function should take a single argument, `row`; it will be passed a jQuery object, wrapping the form that was just added.

```
$('#myFormset1Table tbody tr').formset({
    added: function(row) {
       row.find(".date").datepicker(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Your first idea is a good one.

1. Give all the datepickers a class to identify them from.
2. Clone them all.
3. *Then*, turn them into datepickers using the jQuery `each` function:

.

```
$(".dates").each(function (i) {
    $(this).datepicker();
}
```

So basically, copy all the elements before you activate the datepicker on them.  jQuery's `each` allows you to activate a whole list of elements in one step.

**Edit:** If you need to generate new clones dynamically, you can store the row's HTML in a variable.  When your user adds a row, you can do something like:

```
$(".date", $(rowHTML).appendTo($("#my-form-fields"))).datepicker();
```

which adds in a new row into the form, and then initializes that row's datepicker.

**Edit2:** and the above code is equivalent to

```
$(rowHTML).appendTo($("#my-form-fields")).find(".date").datepicker();
```

Comment: yeah but the clone works at the runtime (dynamically), i mean after the documents are ready. The Add bottom allows to create a new row with their elements. The each function will work only on the default elements, but it couldn't work on the newly created (cloned) elements

Comment: Yeah, it happen to me too. Are you already solved this issue @jargalan ?

Answer (score 1):

You could listen for [onSelect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) or maybe even

`$('.dates').focus(index){
    $($('.dates')[index]) //etc.
}`