# Jquery Datepicker not picking correct element with dynamic django fromset

Tags: jquery, python, django, jquery-ui, django-forms

My question is similar to one mentioned here,
[Duplicate jquery ui problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141731/duplicate-jquery-ui-problem) . But in my question i'm not using dynamic formset script.

How can i use the bootstrap jquery datepicker plugin in both default formset and dynamically generated formset?

Here is what i'm doing to generate clone of last row of table (As i'm not familiar with jquery)

```
$("p").live("click", function() {
    //clone last row to variable
     var row = $('#savings_table tbody>tr:last').clone(true);

     //clear text boxes
     $("td input:text", row).val("");

      //clear selection boxes
      $("select option:selected", row).attr("selected", false);
      //add row
  row.insertAfter('#savings_table tbody>tr:last');
  count = parseInt($("#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS").val(), 10)

  var count = count + 1;
  $("#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS").val(count);

  $(row).each(function() {
      $(this).find('td').each(function(){

        var input_name = $(this).find("input").attr('name')
        var input_id = $(this).find("input").attr('id')
        var input_class = $(this).find("input").attr('class')

        if($(this).find("input").attr('name') !== undefined)
        {
            new_input_name = set_attr(input_name);
            new_input_id = set_attr(input_id);
            $(this).find("input").attr('name',new_input_name)
            $(this).find("input").attr('id',new_input_id)

        }

         if($(this).find("select").attr('name') !== undefined)
         {
            var select_name = $(this).find("select").attr('name')
            var select_id = $(this).find("select").attr('id')

            new_select_name = set_attr(select_name);
            new_select_id = set_attr(select_id);

            $(this).find("select").attr('name',new_select_name)
            $(this).find("select").attr('id',new_select_id)
        }
         });
       });
  //$( ".start_datepicker" ).datepicker();

      return false;
    });

  function set_attr(prop)
  {
  var result_name = prop.split('-');
  var inc_value = parseInt(result_name[1], 10) + 1;
  var new_name = result_name[0]+'-'+inc_value+'-'+result_name[2];
  return new_name
   }
```

I tried by assigning the same class name to date fields and using the same class name called the jquery datepicker plugin and which is working fine. But if add formset dynamically then always the last date field will be selected.

```
$(function() {
    $( ".start_datepicker" ).datepicker();
 });
```

What i'm doing wrong here ?